# Import path affecting python logging logger

Tags: python, logging

I've been battling what is (to me) a really strange problem. I have built a test program for two other python programs. The test program starts the other two by explicitly calling start functions in the individual modules. In order to access the tested programs, I needed to modify sys.path to gain access to the modules which host the start functions, like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set up graceful stop
    set_up_interrupt()

    print(f"HTT PID: {os.getpid()}")

    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../hume/device_controller"))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../hume/hint_controller"))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../.."))

    print("printing sys.path")
    ...
```

This is how the module heirarchy looks, just to give an overview of how the added paths look. The start of the test program (as shown above) is done in htt.py:

```
hume/                           <--- This level is added to sys.path to access 
                                     main modules of both device_controller and hint_controller
  device_controller/            <--- This level is added to sys.path since 
                                     device_controller imports expects this to be 
                                     the path where the program is started from
    device_controller/
      device/
       device_req_handler.py
       settings.py
      __init__.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
  hint_controller/              <--- This level is added to sys.path since 
                                     device_controller imports expects this to be 
                                     the path where the program is started from
tests/
  traffic/
    __init__.py
    htt.py
```

This piece of code is only run when the test program starts. Then, I go on to start each of the programs under test, note that the function `dc_loop` is the target function of a process I start to host the program:

```
def dc_loop(q: multiprocessing.Queue, monitor_queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    """
    Main loop of the dc supervising process.
    :param q: cmd queue of the DC supervisor
    :param monitor_queue: reporting queue of the monitor application
    """
    print(f"dc_loop {os.getpid()}")


    from hume.device_controller import main as dc_main

    # This form of importing the module breaks python logging!
    from hume.device_controller.device_controller.device import settings, \
        device_req_handler

    # new process, needs termination handlers
    set_up_interrupt(dc_main)

    dc_main.test_start(logging.DEBUG)

    # Override the outgoing device request module to use HTT's own plugin.
    device_req_plugin.mq = monitor_queue
    settings.device_req_mod = device_req_plugin

    while True:
        item = q.get()

        if item == "stop":
            print("DC supervisor stopping")
            break
        else:
            print(f"DC supervisor got: {item}")
```

As I commented in the code above, using the import path `from hume.device_controller.device_controller.device import settings, device_req_handler` breaks the python logging of the started program. However, if I change that import statement to: `from device_controller.device import settings, device_req_handler` python logging works just fine. Either way is fine because sys.path has been modified. Also, I need to add both to sys.path in order for imports to work both for the test program and the program under test.

I have set up python logging in each module (in the program under test) like so:

```
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And, on starting, the program under test sets up logging like so:

```
import logging


TOP_LOGGER_NAME = "device_controller"


def set_up_logging(log_level):
    """
    Sets up the messages controller's "root" logger with the starting log level.
    :param log_level: min log level to use for the messages controller
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(TOP_LOGGER_NAME)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()  # Print logging messages

    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="{asctime} {levelname:^8} "
                                      "{module} {message}",
                                  style="{",
                                  datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(log_level)

    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

In my mind, either way of importing should not disrupt logging and I'm confused as to why it does. I set a logger on `device_controller` intending to catch logging message from all python modules living "under" the `device_controller` module (in either the same module or sub-modules), why would this change just because the import path is changed to `hume.device_controller.device_controller...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you need to manipulate `sys.path`, there's something wrong already, doubly so if a directory hierarchy can exist several times in your path, as in

```
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../hume/device_controller"))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../hume/hint_controller"))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../.."))
```

With something like this, if you happen to have `hume/device_controller/foo.py`, you are able to import it in two different ways,

```
import foo
import hume.device_controller.foo
```

etc., and that way lies madness.

Fix things so you don't need to modify `sys.path`, and other problems will be much easier to solve, if they exist at all anymore.

Comment: Although I could not find out the exact reason why logging entries were omitted when importing in a certain way, removing the redundant sys.path entry turned out to help. Keeping each entry unique, now I've made a bunch of changes but logging is no longer a concern. Thanks a bunch!